# How to append strings in linear time

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, big-o

I want to change a string with dashes placed randomly in between groups of characters to a string with dashes in between groups of n characters. I would like to keep this at a worst case of O(n) time complexity. The following soln works but I believe that the string concatenation is slow and would prefer a constant time operation in order to maintain O(n).

```
//Desired string is 15-678435-555339

let s = "1-5678-43-5555-339"
let newString = ""
let counter = 0
let n = 6

if(s.length === 1 || s.length < k) return s
for(let i = s.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(counter === 6) {
        counter = 0;
        newString = "-" + newString
    }

    if(s.charAt(i) !== "-") {
        counter += 1
        newString = s.charAt(i) + newString
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this in under O(n)

Comment: I meant worst case o(n)!! Fixed.

Comment: Isn't that what your code is doing? Thats O(n) ?!

Comment: Hmm, I thought that the string concat is expensive, making it well above o(n). No?

Comment: According to your analysis, what is the Big-O complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: And is there a reason you are iterating over the string in reverse?

Comment: I guess I have not truly analyzed the string prepend operation -- I just assumed it was terrible. I chose reverse to simplify this specific problem where we do 2-6-6. Otherwise it might have been more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is javascript you usually get the most performant solution with the least code, which would be:

```
function* chunk(iterable, size) {
  for(let i = iterable.length; i >= 0; i -= size)
    yield iterable.slice(Math.max(0, i - size), i);
}

let result = [...chunk(s.replace(/-/g, ""), 6)].reverse().join("-");
```

(But thats just speculation, that heavily depends on the engine)

> Hmm, I thought that the string concat is expensive, making it well above o(n).

Usually yes, but some very agressive inlining might optimize it away.

Comment: I fed the data to your function and it did not come out right. Obviously your answer uses a generator solution and is worth looking at but did you test it? Where should I put that in my code?

Comment: Yeah there were some mistakes, should be [fixed now](http://jsbin.com/zonixefuqu/edit?console). Now i would be really interested in a benchmark, have a look at http://jsben.ch

Comment: Excellent. I will look into benchmarking it. However now I am wondering how I might have solved this or something like it for o(n) in the future. I feel like I might not have learned anything.

Comment: Your solution is not bad so I would say that you learned something. However most of the performance assessments you can do in other languages dont work in JS because it is able to optimize a lot. Even bad code runs fast

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language you are operating in, but most have some concept of a StringBuilder, which is just implemented as an ArrayList of strings underneath and concatenated when you ask for the resulting string - usually via a toString() method.

Here is a Java example: https://ideone.com/vHHdHH

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String s = "1-5678-43-5555-339";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  int dashPosition = 2;
  int count = 0;

  char[] ch = s.toCharArray();

  for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if (Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]) != -1) {
      sb.append(ch[i]);
      count++;
      if (count % dashPosition == 0) {
        sb.append('-');
        count = 0;
        dashPosition = 6;
      }
    }
  }
  if (sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) == '-') {
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
  }

  //Desired string is 15-678435-555339
  System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```

Comment: "Not sure what language you are operating in" the question is tagged JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

If this is a real life problem and not homework with arbitrary constraints, you should just concatenate the strings.  On a modern javascript, and especially for short strings like you've got there, this will not present a performance problem under normal conditions.

If you really wanted to minimize the number of strings created, you could construct an integer array of character codes using .charCodeAt(i), and then s = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arrayOfIntegers).  But this isn't something you'd normally have to do.

Comment: This is an easy/medium coding challenge. Many of them require knowledge of the Big-O cheatsheet and hash table tricks at a minumum. This is one of those that requested an o(n) soln.